# mobX pass the props only layer by layer

Tags: reactjs, redux, mobx

Last night, I saw some argument between redux & mobX  in Twitter.

I spent a couple of hours to study mobX. In my opinion, redux is awesome, and Dan is my idol. So I think redux is fast than mobX.

I saw the mobx-react-todomvc. I try to modify it, and I find out it pass the props only layer by layer. It is my problem?

Comment: "Dan is my idol" - Dan is great, but I think people should stop with the mantra that redux is the final answer to all problems when it comes to state management. It is not, same as MobX. It helps great deal, that doesn't mean somebody won't come with a better solution next month.

Comment: @Capaj Yes! I agree, redux is not the final answer, and I hope saw a better solution next month~

Answer (score 2):

that is not a requirement just a personal preference. but you can use context as well, for example by using the mobx-connect package. you can even use dependency injection or simply import the store in the component file if you like. there is no technical requirement to use props at all.

Comment: I agree it ! cause context is an unstable API, so I don't use it unless it is necessary

Answer (score 1):

Thx [`@capajj`](https://twitter.com/capajj/status/741906743521857536?lang=zh-cn)

> I never pass any mobx observables through multiple components by props. Just import them where I need them

I think this is a good answer, and I love this idea!